# Merging a complex data structure of NSArray and NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, merge, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have the following data structure `Snapshot` which is a combination of nested arrays and dictionaries:

```
{"Snapshot": {
    "ask": [
        {
            "price": 101.42,
            "size": 7
        },
        {
            "price": 101.85,
            "size": 5
        }
    ],
    "bid": [
        {
            "price": 89.72,
            "size": 79
        },
        {
            "price": 89.71,
            "size": 158
        }
    ]
}}
```

The existing structure from above should be updated by the price and size entries in the following dictionary / array structure:

```
{"Refresh": {
    "ask": [],
    "bid": [
        {
            "price": 89.71,
            "size": 666
        }
    ],
}}
```

In this example, the value `size` for the `bid` item which has the `price: 89.71` should be updated from 158 to 666. If the price does not exist yet, a new item with the price and size from the Refresh data structure should be added. If `size = 0`, the price and size item should be removed.

I have tried to do this with the methods [addEntriesFromDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000141-BABCIBAA) and [addObjectsFromArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABDAJBD) but did find a solution to my problem.

What would be the fastest way to do this? 
How would you recommend to merge these two data structures?

Thank you!

Comment: Show what you have. Explain the issue you are having with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the dictionaries are named snapshot and refresh...

`snapshot[@"Snapshot][@"bid"] = [snapshot[@"Snapshot][@"bid"] arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:refresh[@"Refresh"][@"bid]];`

More complicated union of the arrays will just require more code.  And if you want price to be a unique key, why not make it a key?

Comment: Oh, but you're talking about decision logic in combining the arrays.   There is a `@distinctUnionOfArrays` collection operator you could use like `@distinctUnionOfArrays.price` though I don't think you can use that sort of keypath unless price is a property on the objects in the two arrays.

Comment: You are right, a good alternative would be making `price` the key.